# Github pull request - Waiting for status to be reported

Tags: github

I have a pull request, build passed on VSTS, but another check "Expected - Waiting for status to be reported" never succeeds, no matter how many times I try to trigger build. I had many other pull requests with no issues.

I am not sure how to tackle this problem, how to debug this? There is no specific info than this:
[image]

Where should I check first to resolve this?

Comment: i gave up on this and disabled.

Comment: The solution is to assume that github actions are unreliable.  Notice that all the answers here are workarounds that basically just have ways to ask github to do something again that should have worked the first time.

Comment: @JamesMoore github actions are reliable and work the first time. Because the posters are giving hacks, doesn't mean that's an actual solution. The problem here more than likely is the status check in branch protection does not match the job name exactly. It's a user error

Comment: @NickTurner That was absolutely not our real-life experience in early 2021.  github actions would often fail to complete successfully.  In late 2022, I think things are significantly better, but I really haven't been using them much lately.

Answer (score 88):

This can happen sometimes, what you can do is to push an empty commit to the branch of the PR. It will re-trigger all the checks you have in CI. This can be done using `git` command.

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

and then force push your branch.

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Comment: If the PR already approved it would then stale the status, because amend would change the commit hash

Comment: @otong That depends if "Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed" is enabled or not.

Comment: Wouldn't `git commit --allow-empty && git push` better?

Comment: @Snailedit this would force you to write a commit message I think

Answer (score 42):

## TL;DR

If this status check is necessary before merging, use a Personal Access Token instead of the default `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` for creating this PR in your github action:

```
- name: Create Pull Request
  uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.YOUR_PAT }}
```

If not, simply uncheck this under repo setting, in your protected branch:

[image]

## Reasons

[There're restrictions on github actions triggering other github actions, by design](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/issues/48). So if you have the setting `x must pass before branch can be merged`, some actions could get stuck in limbo forever.

This is also why "push an empty commit" or "close and reopen the PR" can unstuck it--because then the PR is no longer purely action triggered. This is also why switching to PAT works, because [using `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` implies this PR is github-action-initiated](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow). While using a PAT, it's initiated by a user.

## How to debug

> I am not sure how to tackle this problem, how to debug this? There is no specific info than this: *waiting for status to be reported*

I find other people's debugging process generally more illuminating than the solutions themselves, so, glad you asked! Here's how I came to my conclusions:

- From googling "Expected — Waiting for status to be reported", I got to [this top result](https://github.community/t/expected-waiting-for-status-to-be-reported/16727), where ​I found the above setting change vaguely described in the comments.
- Then from reading the description of this setting, I understood it to mean that the reason I see this status is because I've configured for it to must pass before any branch can be merged, but for some reason this branch does not trigger it.
- So I considered what made this branch different from all the other branches that were triggering correctly. One big difference is that this PR is triggered by another action. Running with this theory, I googled "github action doesn't trigger when PR created by bot", and got [this first result](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/issues/48), which explained why.
- Finally I double checked other similar actions in other repos, and curiously, some action triggered PRs had runs below, but some don't. I compared their definitions, and noticed that the limboed ones were using `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` as token when creating PR, while the correct ones were using PAT. And indeed those PRs were headed by this octopus while the correct ones were headed by user icons:

[image]

Case closed.

Comment: Using a PAT instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN` will make the action able to read/write on all repositories that the account has, right?

Comment: This is because your pipeline failed as some point. Removing restriction is a very bad thing and should not be done.

Comment: And to add, you shouldn't be putting a PAT in the pipeline. It will be there forever. It's best to set up a BOT account and add to secrets. However, GITHUB_TOKEN will not cause the pipeline to fail and should always be used unless you're using cross repo calls.

Comment: Good answer, for the record I had a workflow build explicitly mentioned under the "require status checks to pass before merging" and then did some changes to my workflows - for me the solution was to uncheck this option and check it again

Answer (score 36):

The simplest solution for me was closing the PR and opening it again.
After that, checks where executed as expected.

There's a button on GitHub that makes it very easy.

[image]

Comment: This will also clear Approvals, right?

Comment: @MichaelChirico No, it does not clear approvals

Comment: But you lose all pr comments that may be needed. It's best to see why it's failing, hence no status check

Comment: After trying multiple answers here this is what worked.

Comment: simple and clear solution without changing anything else

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me. Re-opened PR is still stuck in exactly the same way. Trying @Lucia's suggestion next...

Answer (score 18):

I believe you need to double-check that the name of the job in the yml file is exactly the same as in ***Branch protection rule / Status checks that are required.***
Be aware it is case sensitive
I spent some time fixing this issue but it turned out it expected **build** job to finish whereas I had **Build**

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: Can confirm this was our issue. We've updated some jobs and the branch protection rule still had the old action jobs required to pass. When you make a change in your action workflow, you have to manually update the ones under "Require status checks to pass before merging" too.

Answer (score 11):

I found a workaround! You need to create a new PR for the same commit using different branch name. This will kick the build upon completion both original **and** new PR will get status update. Then you can merge the original and close the new one.

If PR was created from remote repository you can pull the ref to your repository locally by following these instructions:

- https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

```
git fetch origin pull/{id}/head:temporary
git push origin temporary
```

Answer (score 4):

For me nothing helped but waiting. The reason was that GitHub was partially down. Check for current status on https://www.githubstatus.com

Comment: It may be rare, but it's still a good tip if nothing else seems to help.

Comment: This happened to me yesterday, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me: close the stuck pull request and reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

One case we seen this happens consistenly is (for example):
when github has required PR build, but in the stages there is no stage what actually runs on PR. So Imaging that we have just one stage but with condition that it runs only on push, cron, api but not on pull_request.

```
  include:
     - stage: sample-stage
       if: type IN (push, cron, api)
       name: stage-name
       script:
         - mysript.sh
```

In this case, the travis will not run, at the github however will be:

> Wating for status to be reported

As mentioned in question.

Comment: ok but what is the solution for that?

Comment: this was a while ago, but I guess adding "pull_request" to  "if type in (...)" part.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it happened when the Workflow was not trigerring. I corrected the branch on which the action should be trigerred and then it worked

Comment: This was the same issue for us, we were expecting to run on certain paths which caused the action not to trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You have to somehow refresh the PR, I changed the base of the to PR to some `other branch` and then back to `master` and it worked.

Comment: This wipes approvals

Answer (score 1):

For our situation it turned out that we had added the following ignore into our workflows because we didn't want the status checks (which are lengthy code scans) to run when changes were just occuring with our actual changes to our workflows.

```yaml
    paths-ignore:
    - '.github/workflows/**'
```

The problem was that the only changes were in the workflows folder and so the status checks are waiting for a run that will never happen. We had two solutions, one was to turn off those status checks for this PR or we removed the `paths-ignore`.  We ended up removing the ignore and this kicked off the status checks (which are totally unnecessary) but it gets us past GitHub just waiting around forever.

Answer (score 0):

To [amels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395676/amels). All that you need it is only rerun build for the branch.
I did it for the PR in GitHub and it helped me.

For example. Go to Jenkins (or where is build can be managed manually) via **details** link and select your branch that relates to your pull request then push "Build Now" link. This action will rerun branch build.
After the build will complete the **merge** button will became accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply restart the jobs using the GitHub UI:

- Click on the Actions menu item. [action_menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBAPb.png)
- Click on your job.
- Click on "re-run jobs" [rerun button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOOmU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If there is conflict with master/main. In my case there was a conflict. I resolved that conflict and pushed another commit. It reworked as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If your checks are starting and then getting stuck on pending , you need to look if the reported status checks are in a commit above that

for me a status badge that was pushed as part of my workflow, did not trigger the status checks to re-run

I had to add an ignore paths

```
on:
  push:
    # only trigger on branches, not on tags
    branches: '**'
    paths-ignore:
      - '**/README.md'
```

When I did that it passed

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that the search results contained two variants of the check names, one including the workflow name and one without.

[image: check search results]

Only the ones without the workflow name (i.e. `validate-lambdas` and `validate-iac`) worked for me - the other two just remained in *Expected - Waiting for status to be reported* status.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to disable the checks to fix this issue.
But I disabled the **Require status checks to pass before merging** rule and ***enabled it again immediately.***

Now when I checked the PR again the build passed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I had the default build as the name `build (16.x)` (because I haven't given it a valid one).

When I edited the workflow file and gave it a new name `Code Formatting`, it wasn't updating the status check to reflect that the workflow succeeded.

To fix it, I had to go to the specific branch on GitHub -> "Settings" -> "Branches" -> "Branch protection rules", select "Edit" on the desired branch (mine was `main`) then under "Require status checks to pass before merging" type in the name of the job:

[image]

Afterwards, I selected "Re-run all jobs" and the status check was successfully updated. You could also add a new commit or force push as mentioned on other answers to get the status check from updating.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned that **merge conflicts** were my problem: "Workflows will not run on pull_request activity if the pull request has a merge conflict. The merge conflict must be resolved first.", like stated here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [CLA-assistant](https://github.com/cla-assistant/cla-assistant) to manage your CLA checks, you might also be able to do the following without interfering with GitHub settings, the PR, etc:

1. Go to https://cla-assistant.io/
2. Sign in via GitHub
3. Select the Three-dot-menu of the repository where the PR got stuck, and
4. Select "Recheck PRs"

This re-ran the check that was stuck for me and completed successfully within a minute.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have specified a pull request type and an unhandled action happens. In my case, I had the following:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, closed]
    branches:
      - main
```

and the error appeared when I added new commits to the PR, which required the synchronize type:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, closed]
    branches:
      - main
```

So be careful when using types.

Answer (score -1):

No need to add empty commits. You can re-run the checks by adding the comment below in the PR:

```
/azp run
```

Comment: Is this only for Azure?

Answer (score -6):

In March of 2022, this still happens.  Refresh your browser (cmd-R on Mac, F5 on Windows/Linux) first.  That worked for me - hope it works for you!