# GitHub checks reset their statuses after push made by a workflow run

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have 2 workflows which have to run on every PR: the first one validates JSON, and the second one generates some changes to it and pushes them as a separate commit to the same PR's branch (so you can review the generated code manually). After the push by the second workflow both of them change their statuses to "Expected — Waiting for status to be reported" and hang like this, despite both workflows had finished successfully.

Is is possible to set up the second workflow so its push won't require any checks?
I've tried:

1. Changing the triggers: for the generation workflow - on pull-request: [opened, reopened], and for "validate-json" workflow - only after the generation succeeds - didn't help;
2. Making a single job from these 2 - didn't help;
3. Using `EndBug/add-and-commit@v9` action instead of

```
run: | 
          # some generation commands
          # ...
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add .
          git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -m "GitHub Action generated"
          git push
```

didn't help as well.

Here are my yml configurations for both the workflows:

generate_blurhashes.yml

```
name: Generate-blurhash

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened]

jobs:
  Generate-blurhash:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
      - name: Generate blurhashes in JSON files
        run: | 
          pip install blurhash-python
          python ci_scripts/blurhash_generator.py
      - uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v9
```

validate_json.yml

```
name: Validate-JSON

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened]

jobs:
  Validate-JSON:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Validate JSON
        run: |
          python ci_scripts/json_linter.py
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you not check generated code into your repository, which will solve this problem, plus lots of others, including needless merge conflicts.

Comment: @bk2204, why? My script generates necessary property needed for my app.

Comment: Then check in your source file to a different location, ignore the intended destination, and just use the script as part of your build process to turn the source file into the right form and location.  You won't need to check in the generated parts at al.

Comment: This is not about source files. These are JSON configs, and i need to check it for validity, so one couldn't push invalid JSON file.

Comment: Have you found any solution so far?

Comment: @NikitaPavlovski nope =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@smocer okay, just FYI, I've found something :)

Recently something called PATs was introduced by GitHub. Some better controlled tokens. What I managed to do:

1. I created a "PAT" (personal access token) in GitHub settings. ("Contents" section was set to **read** + **write**)
2. I passed this token to `actions/checkout`

```
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.WRITE_PAT }}
```

3. Now, since you checkout not with the built-in token but with the externally provided one, your commits are authored by you. Also, since it's the same thing as to just make a commit by yourself, the workflows are triggered (and statuses are set in the end).

So, I hope, this can help. It's not as fast as just to preserve the checks statuses, or, say, to assign these statuses manually and explicitly at the workflow, but still it's some sort of the automation.

**DISCLAIMER!**

Be careful as this PAT is not protected from the "cascade" workflows triggering. The default ci tokens are incapable of triggering workflows for a reason. Since the new token is more "powerful", make sure not to trigger the pipeline multiple at every run.

(Simply, make sure that the commit is not done each time the pipeline is triggered. Ideally, just once.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is also described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169858/7487298